# Auto login form with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I need make an auto login form application with Visual Basic 10.0 for the following code:

```html
</script>
    <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="10" width="50%" height="100%" background="images/bg1222.jpg" style="background-position:right top; background-repeat:repeat-y"></td>
                <td rowspan="10" width="1" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width=100%>
                                <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="778" height="153">
                                    <param name="movie" value="images/hed2.swf">
                                    <param name="quality" value="high">
                                    <embed src="images/hed2.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="778" height="153"></embed>
                                </object>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!--<td rowspan="10" width="0" bgcolor="#000000"></td>-->
                <td rowspan="10" width="50%" height="100%" background="images/bg1223.jpg" style="background-position:left top; background-repeat:repeat-y"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="780" height="30" align="center" valign="bottom" background="images/footer.gif"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="583" valign="top" style="background-repeat:repeat-y;" >
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <center>
                    <form action="/cse/login/login1_check.jsp" name="first" method="post">
                        <table width="25%" height="90" border="0" class='formtable1'>
                            <caption align="top">
                              <strong> User Login </strong>
                              <br>
                            </caption>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="24%" height="32">
                                    <div align="right"> User ID: </div>
                                </td>
                                <td width="76%">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="uid" type="text" >
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="43">
                                    <div align="right"> Password: </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="password" type="password" >
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Login">
                    </form>
                 </center>`enter code here`
```

Say username is  `user` and password is `pass`.

It should be auto filled and clicked in the submit button. What would the code be for Visual Basic 10.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to take all the elements that you want to interact to. If they have an ID, you don't need to search, simply get the element with:

```
Dim elem As HtmlElement = Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myId")
```

If not, you need to search for yours, for example:

```
Dim inputs As New List(Of HtmlElement)(a.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))

For Each elem As HtmlElement In inputs
    If elem.GetAttribute("name").Equals("uid") Then
        '...
    End If
Next
```

To set a value of a input:

```
elem.SetAttributte("value", passwordVar)
```

To click a clickable element (such a submit input):

```
elem.InvokeMember("submit")
```

Or:

```
elem.InvokeMember("click")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.Username) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.Password) Then
        TxtUsername.Text = My.Settings.Username
        TxtPassword.Text = My.Settings.Password
End If
```

Comment: this is not a complete solution

Comment: so better write your own code...this is just to give you an idea how to implement..we will not write the code for you.