# Log Into a Website Programmatically and Stay Logged In

Tags: vb.net

I need to log into a website (reuters.com) once programatically and then I would like to use a cookie so that the site remembers that I am logged into and I don't have to log in everytime I change webpages within the site.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried for now ? Please read on how to ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Reuters do offer a lot of different API to read/write data

Comment: @Simon I've tried quite a few things.  Nothing really substantial enough to mention in my OP.  I've tried logging in with htmlagilitypack witch I found out doesn't work.  I've also tried using the POST method but I haven't been able to make the work successfully.  I've been researching this for quite awhile and decided to post here.

Comment: @the_lotus Could you maybe point me in the right direction on how to best use the APIs and what their benefits are?

Comment: @the_lotus I'm under the impression that the APIs cost money and I am not quite at the stage where it makes sense to spend money on this.  I am still testing out my program.

Comment: HINT: Forcing a website to do something is was NOT designed to do is called **hacking**. If it was designed to do it, they should have some documentation or how to do it. The best bet is to search their site for documentation on this. BTW, API does not mean you have to pay. It means they provided a way to let others work against their stuff, exactly like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

See [Auto login form with Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194519/3453226).

> You first need to get the element that you want to interact to, then set its value.